# convert a WCF Service, to a RESTful application?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, rest

Hey im not getting anywhere with turning wcf into a restful service. So I was wondering if some one can take the basic code when you start a WCF Service application here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfService1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Service:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
```

All I have did is started this WCF service app and opened another VS2010 soultion with a basic form that has a textbox button and label and copyed the service location of the serviceapp in the other solution so when I type a number I get a response from the service.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public ServiceReference1.Service1Client testClient = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = testClient.GetData(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

Really quick and dirty but serves its purpose.

Now if any one can help with code how do you turn it into a restful service?

End part of my config file:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

EDIT update with Justins config code:

So when ever I touch the config file my usual error is this: Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:26535/Service1.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost:26535/Service1.svc    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:26535/Service1.svc'.    The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost:26535/Service1.svc    There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:26535/Service1.svc'.    The request failed with the error message:--<html>    <head>        <title>Operation 'GetData' in contract 'IService1' has a path variable named 'value' which does not have type 'string'. ÿVariables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'.</title>        <style>         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}          p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }         pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}         .version {color: gray;}         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }        </style>    </head>    <body bgcolor="white">            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>            <h2> <i>Operation 'GetData' in contract 'IService1' has a path variable named 'value' which does not have type 'string'. ÿVariables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'.</i> </h2></span>            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.            <br><br>            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.InvalidOperationException: Operation 'GetData' in contract 'IService1' has a path variable named 'value' which does not have type 'string'. ÿVariables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'.<br><br>            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">               <tr>                  <td>                      <code>An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>                  </td>               </tr>            </table>            <br>            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">               <tr>                  <td>                      <code><pre>[InvalidOperationException: Operation 'GetData' in contract 'IService1' has a path variable named 'value' which does not have type 'string'.  Variables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'.]   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateClientFormatter.Populate(Dictionary`2& pathMapping, Dictionary`2& queryMapping, Int32& totalNumUTVars, UriTemplate& uriTemplate, OperationDescription operationDescription, QueryStringConverter qsc, String contractName) +726   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter..ctor(OperationDescription operationDescription, IDispatchMessageFormatter inner, QueryStringConverter qsc, String contractName, Uri baseAddress) +94   System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.GetRequestDispatchFormatter(OperationDescription operationDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint) +137   System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) +659   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost) +3864   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime() +37   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnBeginOpen() +27   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +49   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +261   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +121   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +479[ServiceActivationException: The service '/Service1.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Operation 'GetData' in contract 'IService1' has a path variable named 'value' which does not have type 'string'.  Variables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'..]   System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +11655726   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +194   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, Boolean flowContext) +176   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +275   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75</pre></code>                  </td>               </tr>            </table>            <br>            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>            <b>Version Information:</b>ÿMicrosoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456            </font>    </body></html><!-- [InvalidOperationException]: Operation 'GetData' in contract 'IService1' has a path variable named 'value' which does not have type 'string'.  Variables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'.   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateClientFormatter.Populate(Dictionary`2& pathMapping, Dictionary`2& queryMapping, Int32& totalNumUTVars, UriTemplate& uriTemplate, OperationDescription operationDescription, QueryStringConverter qsc, String contractName)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter..ctor(OperationDescription operationDescription, IDispatchMessageFormatter inner, QueryStringConverter qsc, String contractName, Uri baseAddress)   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.GetRequestDispatchFormatter(OperationDescription operationDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnBeginOpen()   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)[ServiceActivationException]: The service '/Service1.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Operation 'GetData' in contract 'IService1' has a path variable named 'value' which does not have type 'string'.  Variables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'..   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, Boolean flowContext)   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)-->--.
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/ are helpful in understanding rest

Comment: Ahh, yes, WCF sucks for REST (as I mentioned). However, I have updated my answer from an old MSDN article on how to do this more specifically for your case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you had mentioned, this is a new project, so maybe a redirect might help make the process a little more simple?

[Here is an MSDN article about what you are asking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529).

However, I especially suggest looking at [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) to create a RESTful service, as it makes the process extremely easy. WCF definitely does not provide an easy means to accomplishing this. They overcomplicate it in this case IMO.

That would be where I would go with this instead, if this is indeed the beginnings of a project

A more direct answer comes from [This article that is a bit older, but can probably help both understand REST, and how to implement it in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx). And is to specify your GET/POST/PUT/DELETE in a Web[Type]Attribute

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = @"Data?value={value}")]
[OperationContract]
string GetData(int value);
```

Also, you will need to do this in your application's .config (Again for the older, [MSDN article by Skonnard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx))

```
<configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
     <services>
        <service name="Service1">
            <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service1"
                      behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/>
        </service>
     </services>
     <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webHttp">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
<configuration>
```

Which would translate into your config as:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1"
        behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1"
        behaviorConfiguration="webHttp">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed 
          or replaced to reflect the identity under which the deployed service runs.  
          If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false 
           and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to 
          avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webHttp">
           <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Then, you will probably need to add an address attribute to the endpoint so it knows where to look.

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter, why the downvote. I realize this is not a direct answer, but sometimes I have found that to be more helpful. Our job is not to provide blind answers if we see a better path.

Comment: I upvoted you just because I hate anonymous downvoters. Wish SO would force a comment when downvoting

Comment: @flq Thanks, I agree and wonder if that has been posed in meta (probably...will check shortly :)). I did end up providing a more specific answer after seeing Garrith's question below.

Comment: @Garrith Can you post your config? It might help, and I do agree that all the config crap makes things way overcomplicated...that is why I really would like to emphasize ServiceStack.

Comment: @Garrith I have updated my answer to include your config with the necessary modifications. I changed the wsHttpBinding to webHttpBinding, added behaviorConfiguration="webHttp", and the appropriate endpointBehaviors to the behaviors section

Comment: @Garrith This is usually from need the MEX, which you have. This was working beforehand?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9261/discussion-between-justin-pihony-and-garrith)

Answer (score 3):

When configuring a simple WCF REST service, in the past I've had an error similar to what your having. In the article mentioned by Justin:
[A Guide to Designing and Building RESTful Web Services with WCF 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx)
(search for - *Defining the HTTP Interface: [WebGet]*)

You'll notice that the Get methods all take strings.

The error you have is common when you try and convert one of the sample WCF projects to a RESTful one. To fix, simply change the signature of the method and the interface to accept a **string**, as opposed to an **int**, this is what inner exception is complaining about:

> Operation 'GetData' in contract 'IService1' has a path variable named 'value' which does not have type 'string'. Variables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'

original:

```
public string GetData(int value)
```

modified:

```
public string GetData(string value)
```

Here's a simple .config section from a sample project I have, that I know works:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Wcf.Service1">
        <endpoint address=""
                behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                contract="Wcf.IService1"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use WebGet attribute on the operations you wish to be available as a RESTful service.

Use webHttpBinding.

Remember to add  to your behaviors in config.

Should be enough to get it started.

EDIT:

Add a new binding in under your service:

```
<service><endpoint binding="webHttpBinding"... behavior="myBehavior"/>
```

etc - then further to that add

```
<behavior name="myBehavior"><webHttp/></behavior>
```

as an endpointbehavior.

[WebGet] attribute - look into the various options to you to further develop it.

Answer (score 0):

This is example project from codeproject.com. There is need to make

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "?id={id}")]
```

instead of

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}")]
```